# Xcode 8.1 slow when varying for traits

Tags: swift, xcode

When I try to make changes to the storyboard for iPad size class using vary for traits, Xcode 8.1 becomes horribly slow. I am not able to move the views around in interface builder. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not  programming related.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. For anyone facing this in the future, please view as iPad pro 12.9" instead of iPad pro 9.7" while varying traits.

Comment: Good spot. For me the slowness was only when I selected "View as: iPhone 7". When I select any other "View as" option it is perfectly responsive.

Comment: Hmm… note quite: changing the “View as” option fixes the slowness only briefly. After making a few changes of the xib file the slowness appears again until the “View as” option is changed again. Very very lame.

Answer (score 0):

This was a huge pain for me but I finally found the solution: change the "Status Bar" and "Top Bar" Simulated Metrics options to "Inferred" or "None" and Xcode Interface Builder will be usable again.

See below for links to a couple of discussions in the Apple Developer Forums:

- [IB using a lot of CPU and unusably slow in 8.1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66551)
- [XCode 8.1 Xib editing extremely slow and completely unusable. HELP!](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66858)